# html form select option, assign SQL query to each option on select

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have a select option form that is self referencing, How do I assign the SQL query to each select option? so when the user selects, that selection queries the database for that specific table and outputs to page. I have a select option for each table in the database and have created the related queries. Do I need to put the queries into an array? I am stuck on how to advance further. I have included some of the code below. Do I need to create a unique SQL query var for each user option? Any direction would be helpful. Thanks

```
    //this is the first query it gets the count for pagination
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(productCode) FROM products"
        or die ('Cannot Select database');  


    // This  query is just to get the total count of rows
    //$sql = "SELECT COUNT(productCode) FROM products";
    $query = $dbc->query($sql);

$row = $query->fetch_row();
//this is were I am stuck
    if($_POST['productCode'] == ('productCode')) {
    // query to get code records
    $sql2 = "SELECT productCode FROM products";
}
elseif($_POST['productName'] == 'productName') {
    // query to get product name  records
    $sql3 = "SELECT productName FROM products";
} else {
    // query to get all records
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM products";
}
    $list = '';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row['productCode'];
        $name = $row['productName'];
        $line = $row['productLine'];
        $scale = $row['productScale'];
        $vendor = $row['productVendor'];
        $description = $row['productDescription'];
        $buy_price = $row['buyPrice'];
        $quanity = $row['quantityInStock'];
        $msrp = $row['MSRP'];
        $list .= "<table>
        <tr> 
            <td class='center'><strong>Product Id</strong></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='center'>$id</td> 
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$product_line</td>
            <td>$scale</td>
            <td>$vendor</td>
            <td>$description</td>
            <td>$buy_price</td>
            <td>$quanity</td>
            <td>$msrp</td>
        </tr>
        </table>";
    }
    <select name="value">
            <option value="<?=$id; ?>">Product ID</option>
            <option value="<?=$name; ?>">Product Name</option>
            <option value="<?=$line; ?>">Product Line</option>
            <option value="<?=$scale; ?>">Product Scale</option>
            <option value="<?=$vendor; ?>">Product Vendor</option>
            <option value="<?=$description; ?>">Product Description</option>
            <option value="<?=$quanity; ?>">Quanity In Stock</option>
            <option value="<?=$buy_price; ?>">Buy Price</option>
            <option value="<?=$msrp; ?>">MSRP</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: you're question is when ever user select the options,that value should be updated in select box automatically??? am i right??

Comment: no , its whenever the user selects an option, the database gets queried and the results from that selection get posted to the page.Say user selects 'product name' the table in the database named productName gets queried and the result is posted.

Comment: posted means that new value should be visible in select options list?

Comment: I am just not sure on how to assign the query to the to select option value. What I mean by posted is when a user selects and option, database is queried, data is retrieved and displayed on the page.

Comment: is my above question is correct or not?

Comment: no, it is not correct

Comment: Implement 'onchange' event of dropdown,pass selected option and call AJAX. There you can query from database to get the correct page and redirect user.

Comment: Hi, I have to have this all done with PHP. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//SQL table rows system names => 'human names for select'
$rows4Search = array(
    'productCode' => 'Product Code',
    'productName' => 'Product Name',
    'productLine' => 'Product Line',
    'productScale' => 'Product Scale',
);

//build html select options
foreach ( $rows4Search as $key=>&$val ){
    $opinonsString .= '<option value="'.$key.'" '.( $_POST['wattafind']==$key ? 'selected' : '' ).' >'.$val.'</option>';

}

//form
echo '
    <form method=POST>
        <select name="wattafind">
            <option>All fields</option>
            '.$opinonsString.'
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
';

//catch selected option & put it to your query
if ( $_POST['wattafind'] && array_key_exists( $_POST['wattafind'], $rows4Search) )
    $sql = 'SELECT `'.$_POST['wattafind'].'` FROM products';
else
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';

echo "<pre>".print_r($sql,true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I wasn't able to retrieve data from the database all that changed was this : SELECT * FROM products , it changed to what was selected. Thanks for your help.